# How often were Odin and Loki allied?

Tags: norse, odin, lokasenna, loki

In [their answer](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/1391/57) to my question about [Odin and Loki being blood brothers](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/1383/57), chaimedes quotes a footnote in Henry Adams Bellows' translation of the Poetic Edda that claims Odin and Loki were "often allied in enterprises":

> 9. There exists no account of any incident in which Othin and Loki thus swore blood-brotherhood, but they were so often allied in enterprises that the idea is wholly reasonable. The common process of "mingling blood" was carried out quite literally, and the promise of -which Loki speaks is characteristic of those which, in the sagas, often accompanied the ceremony; cf. Brot af Sigurtharkvithu, 18 and note.
>
> <sub>Source: [The Poetic Edda, by Henry Adams Bellows, p.156](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/poe/poe10.htm#page_155)</sub>

I did find a mention to such an enterprise in the Lokasenna:

> 50. "Though on rocks the gods bind me | with bowels torn
>   Forth from my frost-cold son,
>   I was first and last | at the deadly fight
>   There where Thjazi we caught."
>
> <sub>Source: [Poetic Edda/Lokasenna](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Poetic_Edda/Lokasenna), [Wikisource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikisource)</sub>

More details on Thjazi's story can be found in the Skáldskaparmál, which starts with Odin, Loki and Hœnir setting on a journey together.

One adventure, however, is certainly not enough to support Bellows' claim. What other adventures did Odin and Loki share, as allies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is their visit to Regin in *Reginsmál*; this is part of the background for the story of Sigurd, known from the story fo the Völsungs. Odin, Loki and Hœnir are on a journey. Loki kills what he thinks is an otter eating a salmon; the other two approve and they make abag of the skin. Later, they visit Hreidmar, who was the father of Otr, who had taken the form of the otter. Hreidmar and Regin capture the gods, and they have to ransom themselves with gold, and Loki is sent to retrieve it. He does this by catching the third brother Andvari, and takes all his gold, including a ring. Andvari then curses the gold, and Loki hands it over so the gods are released.

There is also the story about how the giant Svaðilfari and his horse were building the walls of Asgard: if he could finish in less than a year, he would get the Sun, Moon, and Freya. Loki cheated him of his payment by shapeshifting into a mare and luring his horse away; the end result of this was Sleipnir, Odin's horse. Not exactly an "adventure together", but Loki is at least an ally.

Finally, there is the story of how Odin, Hœnir and "Lóðurr" created the race of men. Odin gave them "spirit", Hœnir "sense" and Lóðurr "blood". Some scholars have wanted to identify the otherwise unknown Lóðurr with Loki.

Answer (score 1):

Odin Hoenir and Loki appear as a trio in Haustliong the prologue to the theft of Idunn and in Loka Tattur the three are summoned separately to aid a farmer's boy from a giant. After the first 2 fail Loki is successful, arare example oh his doing a good deed without being compelled to do so. Loki may also be Loourr